# error to create big decimal object

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I using the following code and i added the support for big decimal and the compiler show
error on the create object for the big decimal `new BigDecimal(nextRandom)`,how can I overcome it?

All the other types are working as expected.

```
public static SwitchInputType<?> switchInput(final String typeName, final String memberName, final int cnt, boolean random) {
...
} else if (typeName.equals("decimal") || (typeName.equals("java.math.BigDecimal"))) {
    BigDecimal nextRandom = RandomizeValues.nextRandom("9");
    return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal(nextRandom));<-HERE IS THE ERROR

} else if (typeName.equals("boolean")) {
    boolean randomBoolean = RandomizeValues.nextRandom();
    return new SwitchInputType<Boolean>(new Boolean(randomBoolean));
}
```

The error is :

```
The constructor BigDecimal(BigDecimal) is undefined
```

How should I overcome this?

Comment: Please cut your example code down to the **minimum** required to demonstrate the compiler error.

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Why are you creating a BigDecimal object form another BigDecimal object? Seems redundant

Answer (score 6):

You are creating

```
new BigDecimal(nextRandom)
```

where `nextRandom` is a `BigDecimal`. That makes no sense.

Replace the line

```
return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal(nextRandom));
```

with

```
return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(nextRandom);
```

And check if you still get the same error.

Can't say anything else until I see the constructor of `SwitchInputType`